# Comparing a time point with a difference of time points

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

How does one go about comparing the time point `t` with `elapsed` which is difference between two time points? In other words, I am verifying whether time elapsed so far is <= the given time point i.e 100ms.

Shouldn't `elapsed` be a time point itself and comparing with `t` be no issue?

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<Clock>;

int main() 
{
    TimePoint begin = Clock::now();

    std::chrono::seconds delay(2);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay);
    
    auto cur = Clock::now();
    auto elapsed = cur - begin;

    TimePoint t = TimePoint(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));

    if (elapsed <= t)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: A difference between 2 Timepoints is not a Timepoint, it's a Duration. You must compare it with a Duration like `std::chrono::milliseconds(100)`.

Comment: How would you compare May 21 2023 8:20AM with 7 days 20 minutes 11 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between 2 `time_point`s is **not** a [`std::chrono::time_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) but rather a [`std::chrono::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration), which represents a time interval.

Therefore you need to change this line:

```
TimePoint t = TimePoint(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
```

Into:

```
std::chrono::duration t = std::chrono::milliseconds(100);
```

Or simply use `auto` so that the compiler will infer this type:

```
auto t = std::chrono::milliseconds(100);
```

Comment: Fair, thing though is I am using the TimePoint in my program. Perhaps a better approach would be to get the duration out of a time point in milliseconds...

Comment: Duration is by definition the interval between time points. So you cannot get it from a single time point.